# jQuery focus event duplicates on tab change

Tags: jquery, events, focus

This is a very weird bug I've noticed.
Im using the `.focus()` event to append a div to another one when it triggers.
The code is okay and it works fine, however when I switch tab (I mean I open another site) and then return to the one I used the `.focus` event on, the result duplicates.
If you want to see the code just tell me, but it's a simple event call with nothing fancy on 
it.Here is some code

```
<div id="song">
   <input type="text" id="post_title" name="title" value="Artist - Song" /><br />               
</div>

   var songSuggestion = '<div id="titleSuggest" style="width:270px; background:#37819d; color:white; margin:0 auto; ">Try this!</div>';

$('#post_title').focus(function(event){ 
    $(this).parent().append(songSuggestion);
    });

$('#post_title').blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('#titleSuggest').remove();
});
```

[image]
EDIT:
This happens ONLY on chrome, on firefox this never occurs!

Comment: so if yu have 3 text box it will call 3 times for the third one. so you got an idea now. is it

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I tried my best to try and figure out what you're trying to build. If you want to try and elaborate a little more I can help you out. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUrCU/) and the code is just below.

Instead of appending divs i recommend you just hidding a certain div and then revealing the data once the focus function is fired.

HTML

```
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<form>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" />
   <div class="append-div">Try This Out !</div>             

   <input type="text" name="lastname" />        
   <div class="append-div">Try This Out !</div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
html { margin: 10px; }

input { 
  border: 1px solid #000; 
  padding: 3px 7px; 
  width: 200px; 
  margin-top: 10px; 
  display: block; 
}

.append-div { 
  width: 200px; 
  padding: 3px 7px; 
  height: 15px; 
  background-color: #999; 
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d; 
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  display: none; 
  color: #000; 
}
```

JQuery

```
$("input").focus(function() {

   if ($(this).next(".append-div").is(":hidden")) {

      $(this).next(".append-div").show();

   } else {
   }

});
```

​
Have any questions feel free to ask!

Comment: I updated with an example of my code.
Well yes I thought about this as well, but I want the div to be dynamicaly created (check my code)

Comment: This is where I'd normally recommend using server side scripting (PHP, Python, Ruby) But I can try and figure out a JQuery only method.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but couldn't you just do this --> http://jsfiddle.net/z53BF/